# How to change div background color on button click?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I can change the background color Red, Blue, as well as Green,
but when I click the Reset button I get an error in  Chrome(browser):

btnReset is not a function,

How to make all div blank when I click Reset button?

```js
function btnRed() {
  document.getElementById("Div1").style.backgroundColor="Red";
}
function btnGreen() {
  document.getElementById("Div2").style.backgroundColor="Green";
}
function btnBlue() {
  document.getElementById("Div3").style.backgroundColor="Blue";
}
function btnReset() {
  document.getElementById("Div1").style.backgroundColor="Black";
  document.getElementById("Div2").style.backgroundColor="white";
  document.getElementById("Div3").style.backgroundColor="white";
}
```

```css
#Div1
{ 
  z-index: -2;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
}
#Div2
{
  z-index: -1;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 50px 0 0 50px;
}
#Div3
{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 23px 0 0 47px;
}

#DivBtn
{
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Div1">
  <div id="Div2">
    <div id="Div3">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="DivBtn"> <input type="button" id="btnR" value="Red" onclick="btnRed();"> &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="button" id="btnG" value="Green" onclick="btnGreen();">&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="button" id="btnB" value="Blue" onclick="btnBlue();">&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="button" id="btnReset" value="Reset" onclick="btnReset()">
</div>
```

Comment: The code you posted works fine.

Comment: Reset was broken for me after pasting code into local file and running with chrome

Comment: check answer, and change reset ID or reset function name.

Answer (score 5):

Be careful when you're using `id` on the html tags, because it makes an automatic var declaration using the `id`. So, you're overriding the `btnReset` function with the `btnReset` pointing to the `<input>`.

Solution 1: change the `id="btnReset"` or the `function btnReset()` name!

Solution 2: move your `<script>` to the end of the document (just before the `</body>` end tag, so your function overrides the automatic declarated var.

Additional info: http://www.2ality.com/2012/08/ids-are-global.html

Comment: Your first solution worked for me, it was still broken when I tried moving the script at the end of the body though.

Comment: thank you sminutoli, it's work
i don't know about this overriding.

Comment: You're welcome @KarmeshMadhavi, I'm not using anymore IDs for UI, its better to use CSS classes and `document.querySelector` to bind the js.

Answer (score 0):

```
function btnRed() {
  document.getElementById("Div1").style.backgroundColor="Red";
}
function btnGreen() {
  document.getElementById("Div1").style.backgroundColor="Green";
}
function btnBlue() {
  document.getElementById("Div1").style.backgroundColor="Blue";
}
function btnReset() {
  document.getElementById("Div1").style.backgroundColor="Black";
  document.getElementById("Div1").style.backgroundColor="white";
  document.getElementById("Div1").style.backgroundColor="white";
}

#Div1
{ 
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
}




<div id="Div1">
  <div id="Div2">
    <div id="Div3">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="DivBtn"> <input type="button" id="btnR" value="Red" onclick="btnRed();"> &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="button" id="btnG" value="Green" onclick="btnGreen();">&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="button" id="btnB" value="Blue" onclick="btnBlue();">&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="button" id="btnReset" value="Reset" onclick="btnReset()">
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).